How to edit verification email text in Laravel 10 with Laravel Breeze
I am using Laravel 10 and Laravel Breeze. When a user registers a new account, the following code is executed:
event(new Registered($user));

I believe this part of the code is responsible for sending an email verification message. I receive this email at my designated email address.

Everything works as expected, but I need to modify the text in this email. I have searched for the corresponding blade file in every repository but have not found anything. I even tried searching my Laravel project for this blade file using the words in the email.
I also tried using the following command:
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail

However, I didn't find anything significant.
Another thing I found is the following code:
$request->user()->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

This is also used to send the email, but I can't locate the corresponding blade file. I attempted to overwrite this email with another blade file, but despite spending some time on this, it didn't work. Does anyone know how to modify this email without having to overwrite it with a new one? I prefer to edit the file responsible for this email. If that's not possible, how can I write such an email? I have been unable to devise a solution on my own.

Does this help? https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/verification#verification-email-customization

@aynber Yes it helped, but I still need to change for example the inscription Hello! but it will be to change in files that are already normally available?

i need to change header and footer also

You can probably set it to use a template instead of building out the message. See https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/mail#configuring-the-view

I tried to overwrite email blade but i failed on doing so. With your first method i have to change "Hello!" "Regards, Laravel" and "If you're having" and my email is ready to be used

Digging into it slightly, vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/resources/views/email.blade.php is the actual view. Don't edit it! But Laravel comes from APP_NAME in your .env . The rest is all language settings

changing the language in the app didn't work for me either XD

To edit the template you need to publish it with php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
To customize the text have to extend the VerifyEmail class and override buildMailMessage(), and in your User model override sendEmailVerificationNotification() to use your custom class. Also, in buildMailMessage() you can see how lang strings are being used.

Perfect. Thanks :)
